# C# How To Convert From Int ddmmyy to DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, parsing, datetime

Ok, so I have a date stored as an int in the format ddmmyy or dmmyy, with leading 0's cut off, e.g. 10914 or 100914

This value is 0 under certain conditions to represent 000000.

How would I convert this to DateTime without converting to a string first (due to the possibility of it being 0)? Is there some sort of DateTime.Parse overload for it?

Comment: AFAIK no you'll have to convert to a `string` first to use the standard infrastructure. If you are really concerned with performance I fear you'll have to implement it yourself but really I don't think this would be an issue unless you are in a very specific situation... And concerning WPF you'll probably need an `IValueConverter` to do the job.

Comment: You need to convert it to a string first - you can't avoid this, `myNum.ToString().PadLeft("0",6);`

Comment: After your update: if your issue is the format then you'll encounter it also with dates like `010114` so the solution is indeed to pad as mentioned by *Sayse*.

Comment: How do you cut off leading zero? I mean how can one then tell whether 11295 is 02-Nov-95 or 12-Jan-95?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use integer division and modulo functions to break out the three sections, then use use the DateTime(int, int, int) constructor to create your DateTime value.
You will need to change your year into a full four-digit year at some point also.

Something like this:

```
int year = (date % 100) + 2000;
int month = (date / 100) % 100;
int day = (date / 100000);
DateTime result = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

Comment: He said he's dropping leading zeros. So one can't tell whether 11295 is 02-Nov-95 or 12-Jan-95.

Comment: @dotNET I would interpret that as dropping leading zeroes of the final integer value. So if there is a non-zero day, no leading zeroes of the month-part will be dropped. Since it's just an `int`, this is just a matter of representation.

Comment: Look at the example given: 10914 is quite unambiguous as 1-September-2014. If that was represented as 1914 then there would be a problem, but 10914 is perfectly fine.

Comment: That's what I mean. :)

Comment: Read the question. "in the format ddmmyy or dmmyy". There is nothing about the format ddmyy, the allowed formats are ddmmyy and dmmyy.

Comment: Fair enough! +1 from me then.

Answer (score 0):

```
int UrInt = 000000;
GroupCollection groups = Regex.Match(UrInt.ToString(), @"^(?<DAY>[0-9]{1,2})(?<MONTH>[0-9]{2})(?<YEAR>[0-9]{2})$").Groups;
int month;
if (int.TryParse(groups["MONTH"].Value, out month) == false)
{
    month = 1;
}
int day;
if (int.TryParse(groups["DAY"].Value, out day) == false)
{
    day = 1;
}
int year;
string _tmp = groups["YEAR"].Value;
// If the year matches 80-99 it will be 19xx if the year matches 00-79 it will be 20xx
if (Regex.IsMatch(_tmp, @"^[8-9]{1}[0-9]{1}$"))
{
    _tmp = String.Join("", "19", _tmp);
    if (int.TryParse(_tmp, out year) == false)
    {
        year = 1979;
    }
}
else
{
    _tmp = String.Join("", "20", _tmp);
    if (int.TryParse(_tmp, out year) == false)
    {
        year = 1979;
    }
}

DateTime UrDateTime = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

Not the best way, but i think, that will match ur search terms. ;)

*NOTE*

U have to correct the year match to ur needs @"^[8-9]{1}[0-9]{1}$"

Explain:

^ = Line beginning

[8-9]{1} = Match 1st digit 8-9

[0-9]{1} = Match 2cnd digit 0-9

$ = Line end

Hope this helps.